# Using a file to store optparse arguments

Tags: python, optparse

I've been using optparse for a while now, and would like to add the ability to load the arguments from a config file.

So far the best I can think of is a wrapper batch script with the arguments hardcoded... seems clunky.

What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I agree with S.Lott's idea of using a config file, but I'd recommend using the built-in [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) (configparser in 3.0) module to parse it, rather than a home-brewed solution.

Here's a brief script that illustrates ConfigParser and [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) in action.

```
import ConfigParser
from optparse import OptionParser

CONFIG_FILENAME = 'defaults.cfg'

def main():
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(CONFIG_FILENAME)

    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-l",
                      "--language",
                      dest="language",
                      help="The UI language",
                      default=config.get("Localization", "language"))
    parser.add_option("-f",
                      "--flag",
                      dest="flag",
                      help="The country flag",
                      default=config.get("Localization", "flag"))

    print parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
(<Values at 0x2182c88: {'flag': 'japan.png', 'language': 'Japanese'}>, [])
```

Run with "`parser.py --language=French`":

```
(<Values at 0x2215c60: {'flag': 'japan.png', 'language': 'French'}>, [])
```

Help is built in.
Run with "`parser.py --help`":

```
Usage: parser.py [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l LANGUAGE, --language=LANGUAGE
                        The UI language
  -f FLAG, --flag=FLAG  The country flag
```

**The config file:**

```
[Localization]
language=Japanese
flag=japan.png
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`argparse`](http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/ArgumentParser.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) module for that:

```
>>> open('args.txt', 'w').write('-f\nbar')
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
>>> parser.add_argument('-f')
>>> parser.parse_args(['-f', 'foo', '@args.txt'])
Namespace(f='bar')
```

It might be included in stdlib, see [pep 389](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0389/).

Comment: PEP 389 was approved and `argparse` is already part of Python 2.7

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, but also wanted to specific the config file as an argument. Inspired by S. Lott's answer, I came up with the following code.

Example terminal session:

```
$ python defaultconf.py # use hard-coded defaults
False
$ python defaultconf.py --verbose # verbose on command line
True
$ python defaultconf.py --loadconfig blah # load config with 'verbose':True
True
$ python defaultconf.py --loadconfig blah --quiet # Override configured value
False
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import optparse

def getParser(defaults):
    """Create and return an OptionParser instance, with supplied defaults
    """
    o = optparse.OptionParser()
    o.set_defaults(**defaults)
    o.add_option("--verbose", dest = "verbose", action="store_true")
    o.add_option("--quiet", dest = "verbose", action="store_false")

    o.add_option("--loadconfig", dest = "loadconfig")

    return o


def main():
    # Hard coded defaults (including non-command-line-argument options)
    my_defaults = {'verbose': False, 'config_only_variable': 42}

    # Initially parse arguments
    opts, args = getParser(my_defaults).parse_args()

    if opts.loadconfig is not None:
        # Load config from disk, update the defaults dictionary, and reparse
        # Could use ConfigParser, simplejson, yaml etc.

        config_file_values = {'verbose': True} # the dict loaded from disk

        my_defaults.update(config_file_values)
        opts, args = getParser(my_defaults).parse_args()

    print opts.verbose

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

A practical implementation can be found on Github: [The defaults dictionary](http://github.com/dbr/tvnamer/blob/26b0efedc89dfdd5b9bf2d68d8de54a2dd8b9590/tvnamer/config_defaults.py), [the argument parser](http://github.com/dbr/tvnamer/blob/26b0efedc89dfdd5b9bf2d68d8de54a2dd8b9590/tvnamer/cliarg_parser.py) and [the main function](http://github.com/dbr/tvnamer/blob/26b0efedc89dfdd5b9bf2d68d8de54a2dd8b9590/tvnamer/main.py#L198)

Comment: That's great. I've extended it to also show the default values from the config file in --help:

Answer (score 3):

That's what the `set_defaults` function is for.  http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#optparse.OptionParser.set_defaults

Create a file that's the dictionary of default values.

```
{ 'arg1': 'this',
'arg2': 'that'
}
```

Then read this file, eval it to convert the text to a dictionary, and provide this dictionary as the arguments to `set_defaults`.

If you're really worried about `eval`, then use JSON (or YAML) notation for this file.  Or you could even make an `.INI` file out of it and use `configparser` to get your defaults.

Or you can use a simple list of assignment statements and `exec`.

Config File.

```
arg1 = 'this'
arg2 = 'that'
```

Reading the config file.

```
defaults= {}
with open('defaults.py','r') as config
    exec config in {}, defaults
```

Comment: There's no reason to use eval here - you can just use marshal.

Comment: @Nick Bastin:  Eval is not Evil, only the sociopathic end-users who are always trying to hack the application by exploiting the use of eval.

Comment: Wagging your finger at an attacker taking advantage of a chink in your armor neither eliminates the chink or stops the attack... :)

Comment: @Kevin Litle: Who's this mysterious "attacker"?  A co-worker?  The person who purchased the application?  Who specifically?  Please provide the name of this mysterious "attacker" has.

Comment: @S. Lot ;) : I don't _know_ who this mysterious attacker is -- that's part of the problem! Neither do I know where this tiny, "safe" Python applet, into which I'm going stick a naked "eval()" of an externally accessible file, is going to end up in, say, three years. Maybe it will become part of a nifty, public service I never even envisioned, artfully mashed together by trusting developers in the company/community I left a year after I wrote it. But, we digress; sorry!

Comment: @Kevin Little:  Your threat scenarios -- "maybe it will become part of..." is silly.  This is Python.  The mysterious sociopath has access to the source already.

Answer (score 2):

Read the arguments in the same commandline format from a file e.g. @commands, then use your original parser to parse them.

```
options, args = parser.parse_args()

if args[0][0] == '@': # script.py @optfile 
    with open(args[0][1:]) as f:
        fa = [l.strip() for l in f]
    fa = fa + args[1:] # put back any other positional arguments
    # Use your original parser to parse the new options
    options, args = parser.parse_args(args=fa, values=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've built a lot of scripts with flags and options lately, and I've come up with the solution described [here](http://www.maurobianchi.it/node/66).

Basically I instance an optionparser with a special flag that tells to try and load options from a file, so you can use normally your script specifying options from command line or provide them (or a set of them) from a file.

Update: i have shared code on [GitHub](https://github.com/bianchimro/OptionParserWithFileOption)